# What is the difference between "What are you?" and "Who are you?"?

Tags: word-meaning

I am often asked "Who are you?" and "What are you?", but I don't know the difference between these two questions.

Please explain it to me.

Comment: Who is typically addressed to a person, and what to an object so as the other person stated it is odd, especially out of context.

Answer (score 11):

> **Who are you?**

This is typically asking for your name, but a particular context could indicate a different meaning.

> **What are you?**

This question is very informal and bit odd. It is a very terse question which implies some understood context.

- If you're in a business meeting it could be your role - e.g. "I'm the
  accountant"
- If you discussing two sports teams it could mean "Which team are you
  a fan of?"
- If you're in a group that has been discussing the nationality of
  different folks in the group then the question would be asking for
  your nationality.
- If you're in a group of college students discussing what year of
  college you're in then the answer might be "I'm a freshman" or "I'm a
  sophomore."

So in general I'd say that the question is looking for a label for some kind of subgroup to which you belong.

Comment: Who are you is requesting personal information about yourself ("My name is X, I am clerk, and I am 99 years old). What are you is requesting information about your place in a larger group (e.g. "What are you? I am a human.")

Comment: @Anaksunaman - I can't disagree with  the first part. Your name you typically be the first thing wanted and then some other infomation depending on context. e.g "I'm Max, the plumber." Until I get to visit Quark  on Ferenginar I can't image answering "I am a hewman."

Comment: "Arthur Dent? ... Arthur Phillip Dent? ... You're a jerk. A complete kneebiter." - Wowbagger The Infinitely Prolonged. On topic, yes, you likely wouldn't say this to very many people. =P

Answer (score 0):

> What are you?

Here **what** is used to ask your **occupation**.

Who is used to ask only about **name** and **background**.

Answer (score 0):

"What are you?" asks about a person's job.

"Who are you?" asks about your identity.