# Is "What are you?" question only about work?

Tags: questions

Can I use this question to ask nationality, for example?

Comment: [Related](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71824/what-is-the-difference-between-what-are-you-and-who-are-you)

Comment: You wouldn't ask that question ***anywhere*** unless the specific "category type" was already plainly contextually obvious. But that category type could be ***anything*** people could conceivably be classified into different groups by. For example, in the relevant context, ***What are you**?* could mean ***Are you a male or female? / smoker or non-smoker? / native or foreign?*** And they're not just binary choice questions either. You might be asking exactly how much someone weighs, or which specific country they came from.

Comment: A simple "where are you from?" could work...

Comment: ...but note that native speakers would rarely phrase the question that way if they wanted to know what the other person's job was. We ask ***What do you do** [for a living]?*

Comment: Honestly even if the context was obvious it would still sound rude and dehumanising to say it, I think. If you asked someone "what's your nationality?" and then moved on to the next person and said "what are you?" it could sound extremely disrespectful, and seem like you have an issue with people of other nationalities, like "what kind of thing are you?" *How about you?* could work fine though!

Answer (score 0):

You should not normally use that question at all. It treats the person like a thing and so is rude.

If you want to ask about a job ask

> What is your job?
>
> What do you do (for work) (for a living)?

If you want to ask about nationality:

> What is your nationality?

And so on.